# Disable wifi tethering on android

Tags: android, tethering

I've found on stackoverflow the code that activates wifi-tethering programmatically on android... but how can I disable programmatically wifi tethering?
Is available something like `setWifiApDisable`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should disable the wifi tethering.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setWifiTetheringEnabled(false);
}

private void setWifiTetheringEnabled(boolean enable) {
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);

    Method[] methods = wifiManager.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
    for (Method method : methods) {
        if (method.getName().equals("setWifiApEnabled")) {
            try {
                method.invoke(wifiManager, null, enable);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Changing `setWifiTetheringEnabled(false);` to `setWifiTetheringEnabled(true);` will enable the wifi tethering.